# SAPUI5 - How to prevent dialog from closing when navigating to other application?

Tags: navigation, dialog, sapui5, cross-application

I have a sap.m.Dialog which consists a table. The first column of the table has links that will navigate to other applications when clicked.
[image]

I am using sap.ushell.services.CrossApplicationNavigation to navigate to an external application.
[image]

When the user clicks a link, another application will open on a new tab, then the dialog from where I selected the link automatically closes.

I have read that there is a way to prevent the Dialog from closing using `this.getRouter().getTargetHandler().setCloseDialogs(false);` but I think this is applicable only when sap.ui.core.routing.Router is used for navigation.

Also, there is a property "closeOnNavigation" for sap.m.Dialog
[image]

But unfortunately, my UI5 version is 1.71.16

In this scenario, how can I prevent the dialog from closing when I navigate to other apps?